# Delete dimension of array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I have a numpy array of shape (0, 2000, 6). I would like to delete the first dimension so that the array's shape is (2000,6). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Is the first dimension really *0*?  That means there is no data in the array.

Comment: That's impossible; the number of items must be the same after reshaping.

Comment: Yes. The first dimension is really 0. I would like to delete it.

Comment: I believe there's a function like numpy.delete() but I'm not exactly sure how to use it

Comment: Expanding on @larsman's comment: the number of items in the array is the product of dimensions in the shape.  If there is a 0 in there, it means the number of elements in the array is *0*.  So you can't change the shape to something that results in a nonzero number of elements.

Comment: Expanding on @WarrenWeckesser's comment: In fact, if the first dimension is _anything_ but exactly 1, it doesn't make sense to "delete the first dimension". Think about it: If you have a stack of 0 sheets of paper, there's no way to turn that into a sheet of paper by deleting the z axis; if you have a stack of 2 sheets of paper, there's _also_ no way to get a sheet of paper by deleting the z axis—there are two sheets of paper; which one is "the" sheet?

Comment: If what you want to do is take the _first_ sheet (raising an exception if there are no sheets), of course, that's easy: `a[0]`.

Comment: It would help if you gave us a complete example (but obviously a stripped-down one, without that giant `2000` dimension). Show us exactly what you have, and what you want, and we can tell you how to get it.

Comment: @user3776468: Maybe you are thinking of `np.squeeze`?  That removes dimensions with length 1, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

should be

```
output = numpy.delete(arrayName, [:], 0)
```

that is to say:

numpy.delete(array, slice, axis) with [:] indicating all slices and 0 indicating it's the first axis.

This should be the function you are looking for:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

**just reread and not 100% sure this is what you are asking for.